# Why does Mocha skip reassigning the variable when I loop over test cases?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js, chai

I am looking for an explanation into the inner workings of JavaScript or Node.js. I have this unit test:

```
    const assert = require("assert");
    const expect = require("chai").expect;

    process.env.NODE_ENV = "development";
    const run = ["development", "production"];

    for (const environment of run) {

      // $first line: this code is skipped on the second "production" run causing the test to fail
      process.env.NODE_ENV = environment;

      describe(`in ${environment} mode`, () => {

        it(`process.env.NODE_ENV should be '${environment}'`, () => {
          // $second line: When I add the following line, the test is successful
          // process.env.NODE_ENV = environment;
          expect(process.env.NODE_ENV).to.equal(environment);
        });

        // more test cases dependant on environment
    }
```

In my Node.js environment the second `process.env.NODE_ENV = environment;` is always skipped during execution. I come from a Java background. In Java, I never had the experience in single-threaded environment that code just gets skipped. I assume it has something to do with the asynchronous nature of Javascript.

**Please explain why the first line is skipped while the second works**. How can I make reassigning work outside of `describe` and `it`?

Comment: Is `it()` asynchronous?

Comment: How can you tell that it's skipped, since you set it to the same thing on the second line?

Comment: @Barmar It's the mocha test framework. Their documentation https://mochajs.org/api/mocha does not specify.

Comment: If `describe()` or `it()` run asynchronously, they won't run until the loop completes, so `process.env.NODE_ENV` will be the value from the last iteration.

Comment: @Barmar Because I tried the first line first. The test failed. I figured it has something to do with callbacks and async so I added the second line.

Comment: This seems like a weird way to run looped tests. The loop should be _inside_ the test case.

Comment: Post the code that doesn't work, don't mix in code that changes the behavior.

Comment: You guys are making code quality comment while I am looking for an explanation how the language works.

Comment: @Barmar I edited the code by commenting out the second line. It now does not work and fails.

Comment: @Jayce444 All subsequent tests depend on the environment. I want to reduce code duplication inside the tests so I wrap the whole thing.

Comment: You need to move `process.env.NODE_ENV = environment` into the actual test. The test framework doesn’t run any of your tests until the loop has finished, meaning the var has the value from the last iteration even before the first test runs. Your code only describes the tests, it’s the framework that executes them and it does that asynchronously. It’s not so much a matter of how the language works but simply how the test framework is designed.

Comment: @Lennholm Thanks, that's the explanation I was looking for. Write it as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: @EliteRaceElephant Sure! Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line isn’t skipped, but it’s executed for each iteration in the loop even before the first test is run. The test framework doesn’t run any of your tests until the loop has finished, meaning `process.env.NODE_ENV` has the value from the last iteration by the time the first test runs.

Your code only describes the tests, it’s the framework that executes them and it does that asynchronously. That’s why you need to put that line inside the actual test.

It’s not so much a matter of how the language works but simply how the Mocha test framework is designed.